# CircleCI not caching my globally installed node module?

Tags: node.js, caching, npm, circleci

I am trying to cache a command line tool needed for my build process.  The tool is made out of NodeJS.  The build succeeds, but I need it to run  faster.

The relevant parts of my circle.yml look like this :

```
dependencies:    
  post:
    - npm -g list
    - if [ $(npm -g list | grep -c starrynight) -lt 1 ]; then npm install -g starrynight; else echo "StarryNight seems to be cached"; fi

test:
  override:
    - npm -g list
    - starrynight run-tests --framework nightwatch
```

The second `npm -g list` shows *starrynight* available for use, but the first one shows that it is **not** being cached.

```
echo $(npm prefix -g)
```

. . . gets me . . .

```
/home/ubuntu/nvm/v0.10.33
```

. . . so I am assuming CircleCI doesn't cache anything installed globally into nvm.

**Nothing** I have tried gets me my message, *"StarryNight seems to be cached"*.

How can I cache *starrynight*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  Thanks to Hirokuni Kim of CircleCI for pointing me in the right direction.

The relevant bits of the new `circle.yml` looks like this :

```
machine:
  node:
    version: 0.10.33

dependencies:
  cache_directories:
    - ~/nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/starrynight
    - ~/nvm/v0.10.33/bin/starrynight
  pre:
    - if [ ! -e ~/nvm/v0.10.33/bin/starrynight ]; then npm install -g starrynight; else echo "Starrynight seems to be cached"; fi;
```

Hirokuni suggested caching `~/nvm` but cache retrieval took as long as the build, since it restores every available version of `nodejs`.

I had tried previously to cache just `~/nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/starrynight` on its own, without realizing that the sister 'directory' `bin/starrynight` is actually an essential symlink to the entry point of the module.

My working assumption is that NodeJS modules run from the command line through a series of symbolic references, probably as follows. . .

`npm install -g starrynight` creates two new artifacts:

- an environment alias for `npm` named `starrynight`
- a symlink in the `${prefix}/bin` directory, which points to the entry point file, `starrynight.js` specified with the `bin` key in `package.json`.

When the user types `starrynight` as a CLI command the shell interprets it as an alias for `npm` and executes it.  `npm` examines $0, gets `starrynight`, and starts up `nodejs` with the symlink `${prefix}/bin/starrynight` as the module to execute.  That symlink refers to `~/nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/starrynight` where the real action takes place.

In short, it is necessary to cache both `${prefix}/lib/node_modules/xxx` and `${prefix}/bin/xxx`

Answer (score 2):

The path in the accepted answer doesn't seem to work anymore. I've checked on the build instance that now global npm packages are in

```
/opt/circleci/nodejs/<version>
```

so I've added to the circle.yml the following:

```
- "/opt/circleci/nodejs/v4.3.2/lib/node_modules"
- "/opt/circleci/nodejs/v4.3.2/bin"
```